# Using a const as both an object and a type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

We have a class that we need to use as both an object and as an interface. The class has a really long name, so we threw it in to a constant, but then strange things happened:

```
class MyClassWithAReallyLongNameThatIsAnnoyinToUse {
    constructor(public name: string) {}
    static className = "SomeThing:MyClassWithAReallyLongNameThatIsAnnoyinToUse";
}

// Convenience const to shorten
const MyClassConst = MyClassWithAReallyLongNameThatIsAnnoyinToUse;

let someFunction = (staticClassObject: Object, callback) =>  {};

// this errors, saying 'Cannot find name MyClassConst'
someFunction(MyClassConst, (cmd: MyClassConst) => { /* do some thing */ });
```

However, if we throw in the `type` alias just below the `const`, it works:

```
class MyClassWithAReallyLongNameThatIsAnnoyinToUse {
    constructor(public name: string) {}
    static className = "SomeThing:MyClassWithAReallyLongNameThatIsAnnoyinToUse";
}

// Convenience const to shorten
const MyClassConst = MyClassWithAReallyLongNameThatIsAnnoyinToUse;
type MyClassConst = MyClassWithAReallyLongNameThatIsAnnoyinToUse;  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<

let someFunction = (staticClassObject: Object, callback) =>  {};

// this is fine
someFunction(MyClassConst, (cmd: MyClassConst) => { /* do some thing */ });
```

But this seems really odd. Not only are we sort of mutating a const, but we're defining the same thing twice with the same assignment, just different keywords; and because using the plain long class name in each location of the const instead works perfectly fine. It only seems to raise an issue when the class is proxied through the const (or let or var, tried them as well).

Is this just a quirk we have to live with, or is there something we can call on the const to get the type? Or is there another assignment we're missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type aliases, like interfaces, don't survive the compilation process and are not part of the compiled javascript.
You can't assign a type alias into a variable, you can't pass it as a parameter to a function, it does not exist in runtime.

On the other hand you can't use a variable as a type:

```
let a = "string";
let b: a; // Error: Cannot find name 'a'
```

You simply use them differently, and because of that there's no conflict in naming both a type alias and a variable in the same name.
Works the same with interfaces:

```
const MyString = "astring";
interface MyString {
    doSomethingSpecial();
}
```

Because of that there's no "mutating" of the `MyClassConst` const.
Classes (and enums) can be used as types, but they also exist at runtime, so you can assign them in a variable or pass them to functions.
Therefor you get an error trying this:

```
type MyType = string; // Error: Duplicate identifier 'MyType'
class MyType {} // Error: Duplicate identifier 'MyType'

enum MyOtherType {} // Error: Duplicate identifier 'MyOtherType'
let MyOtherType = 3; // Error: Duplicate identifier 'MyOtherType'
```

Regardless of this, you should avoid using the `Object` type as it states in the [docs for the any type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any):

> The any type is a powerful way to work with existing JavaScript,
>   allowing you to gradually opt-in and opt-out of type-checking during
>   compilation. **You might expect Object to play a similar role, as it
>   does in other languages. But variables of type Object only allow you
>   to assign any value to them - you can’t call arbitrary methods on
>   them, even ones that actually exist**

So you better use `any`, but you can also do:

```
class MyClassWithAReallyLongNameThatIsAnnoyinToUse {
    constructor(public name: string) {}
    static className = "SomeThing:MyClassWithAReallyLongNameThatIsAnnoyinToUse";
}

type MyClassConst = MyClassWithAReallyLongNameThatIsAnnoyinToUse;
type MyClassConstructor = {
    new (name: string): MyClassConst;
    className: string;
}
type MyClassHandler = (cmd: MyClassConst) => void;
const MyClassConst = MyClassWithAReallyLongNameThatIsAnnoyinToUse;

let someFunction = (staticClassObject: MyClassConstructor, callback: MyClassHandler) => { };

someFunction(MyClassConst, (cmd: MyClassConst) => { /* do some thing */ });

const MyString = "astring";
interface MyString {
    doSomethingSpecial();
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20MyClassWithAReallyLongNameThatIsAnnoyinToUse%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20name%3A%20string)%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20className%20%3D%20%22SomeThing%3AMyClassWithAReallyLongNameThatIsAnnoyinToUse%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20MyClassConst%20%3D%20MyClassWithAReallyLongNameThatIsAnnoyinToUse%3B%0Atype%20MyClassConstructor%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20new%20(name%3A%20string)%3A%20MyClassConst%3B%0A%20%20%20%20className%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0Atype%20MyClassHandler%20%3D%20(cmd%3A%20MyClassConst)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0Aconst%20MyClassConst%20%3D%20MyClassWithAReallyLongNameThatIsAnnoyinToUse%3B%0A%0Alet%20someFunction%20%3D%20(staticClassObject%3A%20MyClassConstructor%2C%20callback%3A%20MyClassHandler)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0A%0AsomeFunction(MyClassConst%2C%20(cmd%3A%20MyClassConst)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%2F*%20do%20some%20thing%20*%2F%20%7D)%3B%0A%0Aconst%20MyString%20%3D%20%22astring%22%3B%0Ainterface%20MyString%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20doSomethingSpecial()%3B%0A%7D%0A))

Comment: I completely missed the OPs part about the type alias, so I re-wrote the answer